Help understanding proof of error bound on Simpson's quadrature rule
I have found the following proof of the error bound for Simpson's quadrature rule:
Using Newton's interpolation method, we derive a cubic polynomial $p_3(x)$ that interpolates $f(x)$ at the points $a, b$, and $(a + b)/2$ and additionally interpolating $f'(x)$ at $(a + b)/2$. Therefore, $p_3(x)$ is given by
$$p_3(x) = p_2(x) + c_2 (x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right).$$
Integrating both sides, we obtain
\begin{align*}
        \int_a^b p_3(x) \ dx = \int_a^b p_2(x) \ dx + c_2 \int_a^b (x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
Noting that the cubic function $(x - a)(x - b)(x - (a + b)/2))$ is an odd function with a root at $(a + b)/2$, we have that its integral on the interval $[a, b]$ evaluates to 0. Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
        \int_a^b p_3(x) \ dx &= \int_a^b p_2(x) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
Now, we have that the error may be represented as
\begin{align*}
        E_S &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_2(x) \ dx \\
        &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_3(x) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
From study of polynomial interpolation, we know expression of the error of $f(x) - p_3(x)$ and thus we have
\begin{align*}
        E_s &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_3(x) \ dx \\
        &= \int_a^b \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!}(x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right)^2 \ dx \\
        &= \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!} \cdot -\frac{(b - a)^5}{120} \\
        &= -\frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)(b - a)^5}{2880}.
    \end{align*}
Some questions:
Why exactly is it important that we derive $\int_a^b p_3(x) = \int_a^b p_2(x)$? We know equally as much about the error of $f(x) - p_2(x)$, so why must we express it in terms of $p_3(x)$? Furthermore, why is the $(x - (a + b)/2))$ term in the expansion of $f(x) - p_2(x)$ squared? This seems like a clever approach compared with some more common approaches to the proof, I am just having a hard time understanding some of the nuances.

Crossposted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/44145/19136

You use the mean value property of integration towards the end of the analysis. What critical property is satisfied by the error function associated with $p_3$ rather than $p_2$?

@CarlChristian Are you referring to the fourth derivative present in $p_3$ but not $p_2$? I see that, I just don't understand WHY we need the fourth derivative.

No, consider all conditions needed for the generalized mean value theorem of integration.

@CarlChristian Ok, I am a bit lost but I am assuming it is something to do with the fact that $(x - a)(x - b)(x - \frac{(a + b)}{2})^2$ does not change sign on the interval $[a, b]$ which is a condition of the generalized MVT for integrals (?) Thank you. Will you mind explaining why exactly the root $(x - \frac{(a + b)}{2})$ has multiplicity 2 in the error function for $p_3$? I thought the error was defined as
$$\frac{f^{(n + 1)}(\xi_t)}{(n + 1)!} \prod_{i = 0}^n (t - t_i)?$$
I am bit confused on the initial expression of the polynomial $p_3$ and how it interpolated $f'(x)$ at the midpoint.

Indeed, you have named the critical condition satisfied by the polynomial that is named $p_3$. There is another point to consider. Is $p_3$ a good name? How many conditions is $p_3$ supposed to satisfy? Can this actually be done with a polynomial of degree $3$? Are you quite sure that the formula for $p_3$ is correct? It might be helpful to consider a polynomial that interpolates $f$ at 4 nodes, say, $-a, -h, h, a$ and then let $h$ tend to zero. Does its derivative match $f'$ at $0$? In any case, the error formula that you quote refers to the case of distinct nodes.

Well, $p_3$ is a cubic function and we don't want it to interpolate $f$ at 4 nodes, rather we want it to interpolate $f$ at 3 nodes and additionally interpolate $f'$ at one of the 3 nodes. I guess it makes sense, though. The error expression $f(x) - p_2(x)$ has only degree $n + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3$ and hence does not satisfy the conditions needed for IMVT. However, the error expression $f(x) - p_3(x)$ is an even function (degree 4) and the root at the midpoint has multiplicity 2, so it satisfies the conditions. Then we have $\int p_2 = \int p_3$, whence the error expressions are equivalent.
